# Targetting specific div through class with jquery draggable/droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

When dragging a div using jquery UI and dropping it into a UI droppable div, I want to trigger a jquery animation on the div being dropped into the area. When the animation is triggered, it is called on all divs with class = "drag-element" but I want only the specific dragged and dropped element to be animated. I have tried including removeClass(".drag-element") and addClass(".animate-element") and telling animate() to act on that but it is still applying the animation to all .drag-element divs. How do I do fix this?

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
$( ".drag-element" ).draggable({ containment: ".container" }).removeClass(".drag-vid");
$( ".drop-field" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $(".drag-element").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    $( this )
      .css("background-color", "silver");
  }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NBHMT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ui.draggable.animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
```

Instead of:

```
$(".drag-element").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kAG6q/

What happened with your code is when you call `$(".drag-element").animate(....` It selects all the drag-element divs. Instead drop function has a ui argument which provides you information about the dragged element using `ui.draggable`

Comment: this may be out of scope (I will accept, no doubt) but is there a way to get animate to not increase the size of the containment area? When I drop an element into the droppable area and the animation triggers, it makes the area bigger.

Comment: Is it increasing the containment area? i dont see that. But only thing is that it is going beyond the droppable container due to the left positioning when dropped too much into the container.

Comment: when you try to drag another element into the container after dropping the first one, you can now drag it farther to the right if the animation pushed the first div outside of the area.